# Pandas DataFrame - check if string in column A contains full word string in column B

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns `foo` which contains a string of text and `bar` which contains a search term string.  For each row in my dataframe I want to check if the search term is in the text string **with word boundaries**.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':["the dog is blue", "the cat isn't orange"], 'bar':['dog', 'cat is']})

df
      bar                   foo
0     dog       the dog is blue
1  cat is  the cat isn't orange
```

Essentially I want to vectorize the following operations

```
re.search(r"\bdog\b", "the dog is blue") is not None  # True
re.search(r"\bcat is\b", "the cat isn't orange") is not None  # False
```

What's a *fast* way to do this, considering I'm working with a few hundred thousand rows?  I tried using the [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method but couldn't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply your function to each row:

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\b' + x.bar + r'\b', x.foo) is not None, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\b{0}\b'.format(x.bar), x.foo) is not None, axis='columns')
```

df.apply applies a generic function to pandas row or columns 
see more here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html